# Why do TypeScript decorators on a base class cause extensions to affect one another?

Tags: typescript, decorator

Suppose you have a decorator that tracks which fields it decorates:

```
interface FieldTracker {
    fields: string[];
}

const decorator = <T extends FieldTracker>(target: T, fieldName: string) => {
    target.fields = target.fields || [];
    target.fields.push(fieldName);
};
```

Then suppose you create an abstract `Base` class which uses that decorator:

```
abstract class Base implements FieldTracker {
    fields: string[];

    @decorator
    a: string = 'a';
}
```

Then you create two classes which extend the `Base` class.

```
class FirstClass extends Base {
    @decorator
    b: string = 'b';
}

class SecondClass extends Base {
    @decorator
    c: string = 'c';
}
```

Upon instantiating the `SecondClass`, its `fields` will include the field decorated in `FirstClass`:

```
const secondInstance = new SecondClass();

expect(secondInstance.fields).toEqual(['a', 'c']);
```

This results in:

```
Expected value to equal:
  ["a", "c"]
Received:
  ["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### Some observations

- If I log the arguments to `decorator`, I get:

  1. `target: Base {}, fieldName: 'a'`
  2. `target: FirstClass {}, fieldName: 'b'`
  3. `target: SecondClass {}, fieldName: 'c'`
- Note that `Base` is `abstract` and cannot be instantiated. How is `target` an instance of it?
- Note that I never even instantiated `FirstClass`. How is `target` an instance of it?
- If I do not use `decorator` on `Base`, this does not occur. This implies that `fields` is on `Base.prototype`, which seemingly should not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion here.

- The `abstract` nature of the `Base` class just means that the compiler will yell at you if you try to directly construct an instance of `Base` with it.  It still has all the apparatus of a class constructor, including possessing a `prototype`.  You can see this if you examine the emitted JavaScript of your code at [the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20FieldTracker%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20decorator%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20FieldTracker%3E%28target%3A%20T%2C%20fieldName%3A%20string%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target.fields%20%3D%20target.fields%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target.fields.push%28fieldName%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Base%20implements%20FieldTracker%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40decorator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27a%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FirstClass%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40decorator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27b%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SecondClass%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40decorator%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20string%20%3D%20%27c%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20secondInstance%20%3D%20new%20SecondClass%28%29%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%28secondInstance.fields%29%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log%28Base.prototype.fields%29%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%28FirstClass.prototype.fields%29%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%28SecondClass.prototype.fields%29%3B).
- The decorator is acting on the `prototype` of each class constructor (so when you decorate `Base` it is modifying `Base.prototype`).  It is not acting (directly) on any instances of the class.  The decorator gets called exactly once for each class you decorate.
- The `prototype` of a subclass [*inherits from*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Subclasses_and_inheritance) the `prototype` of the superclass.  This way, the prototype chain for an instance of the subclass includes the subclass constructor's `prototype` as well as the superclass constructor's `prototype`.
- If you assign an array to a variable, you are not copying the array's contents; there is only one array object, and any changes you make to it from one variable will be visible from the other.

With all that being said, let's examine your decorator:

```
const decorator = <T extends FieldTracker>(target: T, fieldName: string) => {
    target.fields = target.fields || [];  // hmm
    target.fields.push(fieldName);
};
```

In the line labelled `// hmm`, you are examining the passed-in `prototype` object for its `fields` property.  For `Base.prototype`, this won't exist and will be initialized to a new empty array.  For `FirstClass.prototype`, this will not be found directly, but since `FirstClass.prototype` inherits from `Base.prototype`, it will be found there.  By setting `FirstClass.prototype.fields` to `Base.prototype.fields` you are adding the property directly to `FirstClass.prototype`, but the value is the same array object as on `Base.prototype`.  When you push a value onto `FirstClass.prototype.fields`, you will see the change on `Base.prototype.fields` as well.  And analogously for `SecondClass.prototype.fields`.

Which means you get the undesirable behavior:

```
console.log(Base.prototype.fields);  // Array [ "a", "b", "c" ]
console.log(FirstClass.prototype.fields); // Array [ "a", "b", "c" ]
console.log(SecondClass.prototype.fields); // Array [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

---

The fix for this is pretty simple; don't copy the array reference, but copy its contents to a new array.  The easiest way to do this is with the original array's [`slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
const decorator = <T extends FieldTracker>(target: T, fieldName: string) => {
    target.fields = (target.fields || []).slice();  // all better
    target.fields.push(fieldName);
};
```

Now if you run your above code the tests should pass.  Specifically, you should see:

```
console.log(Base.prototype.fields);  // Array [ "a" ]
console.log(FirstClass.prototype.fields); // Array [ "a", "b" ]
console.log(SecondClass.prototype.fields); // Array [ "a", "c" ]
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this more or less confirms what I'd discovered debugging the issue after I posted the question. My confusion stemmed largely from a misunderstanding of how `abstract class` works. I'd assumed because you can't instantiate it, it was not directly omitting code but instead materializing on inheriting classes. I'll try to adopt your proposed solution in my more complex case. If it works, I'll follow up with a green checkmark shortly!